# Select rows where there is no many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 4 app, I have two models:

`ChallengeList` and `Challenge`

and

`Challenges` has many `ChallengeList` and vice versa (many-to-many).

I want to create a scope such that it selects those Challenges that are not associated with a particular ChallengeList id. But I cant get it to work!

I've tried the following method

```
joins(:challenge_lists).where("challenge_lists.id != ?", id)
```

But this doesn't select items which aren't associated with any challenge list, only those that *are*, and do not have that particular id.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a **left join**.  If so please try the following:

```
joins(
  'left join challenge_lists on challenges.id = challenge_lists.challenge_id'
).where(
  'challenge_lists.id != ?', id
)
```

Comment: Addition: `OR challenge_lists.id IS NULL`